# struct.pack() returns a blank value

Tags: python, arrays, int, hex, struct.pack

When I try to do the following:

```
struct.pack("B",32)
```

The 32 is a `int` type.

I am expecting `"\x20"`, but I get the following (blank): `" "`

I need this as a byte using `struct()` because I want to put it in a `bytearray()`, to look like this:

```
bytearray(b'\x20')
```

I've tried other encoding on the `struct.pack()` besides "B", but I could've left something out.

Comment: If you print the content of a bytearray, all bytes whose values correspond to an ASCII character are represented by that character, for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this:

```
>>> b" " == bytearray(b"\x20")
True
```

you will see that you *are* getting what you are expecting, just in a representation that you are not expecting.

Comment: Yes, I what you mean now. I was concerned that this was being converted to some other type of value which wasn't what I wanted. Other people's answers/comments also say the same, but I'll mark your answer as it is the clearest in explaining this so far. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

space char is 0x20 on the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/mobile/)

```
>>> print(b'\x20')
b' '
>>> struct.pack('B', 32)
b' '
```